# Laser scan has one point

Tags: ros, pointcloud-to-laserscan, laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While using pointcloud to laserscan, I am encountering problems. The scan is only outputting one point... How do I fix this?

Here is my [Bag file.](http://www.mediafire.com/?2h2wswcwuo8l6kt) It contains the pointcloud and the single point laser scan. It should definitely have more points in the output scan, but I have no idea how to make it so...

---

I believe I have located the issue... In the cloud_to_scan.cpp file, the following code is found:

```
void callback(const PointCloud::ConstPtr& cloud)
  {
    sensor_msgs::LaserScanPtr output(new sensor_msgs::LaserScan());
    output->header = cloud->header;
    output->header.frame_id = output_frame_id_; // Set output frame. Point clouds come from "optical" frame, scans come from corresponding mount frame
    output->angle_min = angle_min_;
    output->angle_max = angle_max_;
    output->angle_increment = angle_increment_;
    output->time_increment = 0.0;
    output->scan_time = scan_time_;
    output->range_min = range_min_;
    output->range_max = range_max_;

    uint32_t ranges_size = std::ceil((output->angle_max - output->angle_min) / output->angle_increment);
    output->ranges.assign(ranges_size, output->range_max + 1.0);

    for (PointCloud::const_iterator it = cloud->begin(); it != cloud->end(); ++it)
    {
      const float &x = it->x;
      const float &y = it->y;
      const float &z = it->z;

      if ( std::isnan(x) || std::isnan(y) || std::isnan(z) )
      {
        NODELET_DEBUG("rejected for nan in point(%f, %f, %f)\n", x, y, z);
        continue;
      }

      if (-y > max_height_ || -y < min_height_)
      {
        NODELET_DEBUG("rejected for height %f not in range (%f, %f)\n", x, min_height_, max_height_);
        continue;
      }

      double range_sq = z*z+x*x;
      if (range_sq < range_min_sq_) {
        NODELET_DEBUG("rejected for range %f below minimum value %f. Point: (%f, %f, %f)", range_sq, range_min_sq_, x, y, z);
        continue;
      }

      double angle = -atan2(x, z);
      if (angle < output->angle_min || angle > output->angle_max)
      {
        NODELET_DEBUG("rejected for angle %f not in range (%f, %f)\n", angle, output->angle_min, output->angle_max);
        continue;
      }
      int index = (angle - output->angle_min) / output->angle_increment;


      if (output->ranges[index] * output->ranges[index] > range_sq)
        output->ranges[index] = sqrt(range_sq);
      }

    pub_.publish(output);
  }
```

it appears to be using the x and z for conversion... My code works in the x and y plane, not x and z. How should I fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36228/laser-scan-has-one-point/) by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3055 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [laserscan message definition](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) it says the following:

```
                     # in frame frame_id, angles are measured around 
                     # the positive Z axis (counterclockwise, if Z is up)
                     # with zero angle being forward along the x axis
```

So if you want to stay conform, you'd have to change your code to use the x-y-plane. If your scanner is turned mounted, adjust its tf frame to reflect that position.

---

*Updated..*

First, your bag file only contains only the laserscan, so I couldn't reproduce everything. *rosbag info CloudAndScan.bag* shows some stats.

The pointcloud indeed *is* expected to be in a *camera frame*. See [parameters docs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan#Parameters) and [part 2) on this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/10595/doubts-about-pointcloud-to-laser-scan/?answer=15629#post-id-15629). I think you only have to adjust your frame information.

If it won't work, I'd ask you to update your question with your pointcloud_to_laserscan parameters and upload a bag with scan, cloud and tf.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-06-12**:
The code I posted is not mine. I coded in the x-y-plane.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-06-12**:
Oh, sorry for misunderstanding, updating my answer in a moment..